# Codeigniter - Ajax Post not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm figuring out what's the problem on my ajax function.
I've already create like this before but now it's not working.

The `insert_data` function is working, I try to alert `username` and `password` and it's working but in my `ajax` function, it's returning the `alert('error')`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#send").click(function(){

            username= $('#username').val();
            password =  $('#password').val();

                insert_data(username,password);
             });

            function insert_data(username,password){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "my_controller/insert_data",
                        method: 'POST'
,                        data:
                        {
                            username: username,
                            password: password

                        },
                        success:function(data)
                        { 
                            alert('success');
                            //toastr.success('Data Successfully inserted!');
                           // clearAllmale();
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
            }

});

</script>
```

Comment: it's something in your controller, also "url" in ajax function is a file directory or a url in your localhost?

Comment: Please check your url working or not?

Comment: you can test like this data:{'uesrname':username,'password':password} . if wont fixed you can check your url that is correct? and if not post for us your insert_data action,if you are able to show us request respone in network tab  from google chrome developer its perfect

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi I checked the network tab and its says Object not found error 404. its the url right?

Comment: yeah its right,you have to correct your url

Comment: ok now it works, base_url is not working, so I use site_url. thanks I've learn how to use the network tab in developers tool. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `base_url()` in url to request via ajax and load `url` helper.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#send").click(function(){

            username= $('#username').val();
            password =  $('#password').val();

                insert_data(username,password);
             });
     });
         function insert_data(username,password){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo base_url('my_controller/insert_data'); ?>", // complete url from siteurl/constroller/function
                            method: 'POST'
    ,                        data:
                            {
                                username: username,
                                password: password

                            },
                            success:function(data)
                            { 
                                alert('success');
                                //toastr.success('Data Successfully inserted!');
                               // clearAllmale();
                            },
                            error:function(){
                                alert('error');
                            }
                        });
                }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place function outside of onclick, also double check the URL too

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#send").click(function(){

        username= $('#username').val();
        password =  $('#password').val();

            insert_data(username,password);
         });



});

function insert_data(username,password){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "my_controller/insert_data",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:
                    {
                        username: username,
                        password: password

                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    { 
                        alert('success');
                        //toastr.success('Data Successfully inserted!');
                       // clearAllmale();
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
        }
```